# If a square matrix is positive definite, is the element-wise exponential mapped matrix also positive definite (semi-definite)?

Tags: linear-algebra

If a square matrix is positive definite, is the element-wise exponential mapped matrix also positive definite? Moreover, if the we denote the element-wise mapping function as f(x), what property of f is required to keep the positive definite property of the matrix?

For example, for a 2x2 positive definite matrix, it's quite easy to prove that if f(x)=x^n (n>=1), the resultant matrix is also positive definite, thus the exponential mapped matrix. If this property also holds for high-dimensional matrix?

Comment: Do you know the result: if $A > 0, B > 0$, then $A \circ B > 0$? Here $A \circ B$ stands for Hadamard product of $A$ and $B$ (i.e., elementwise product).

Comment: @Zhanxiong Just got to know this theorem. Really solved my problem!